# Dynamic navigation shows incorrect result count

Tags: google-search-appliance

When we filter result by Duplicate Snippet filter (filter=p) we receive incorrect result count in dynamic navigation.

E.g.

[Picture with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgKCB.png)

Actual result count = 5

Result are shown for end-user = 3 (Two pages was filtered)

Dynamic navigation by content format(Web Pages) = 5

As I know GSA has some problems with determinating actual count for a large number of results.

Is it possible to set filtered result count in dynamic navigation (Web Pages)?

GSA System Version: 7.2.0.G.252

Comment: please provide more details and read How to ask stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please try to translate your print screen.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's my firts question here, I've added picture related to my question.

Comment: The actual result count is 5, is it not?  If you click the "repeat the search with omitted results" do you not see 5 results in total?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but we use custom template and we don't have "repeat the search with omitted results" functionality there. It would be great to show  filtered results count for end-users. I think I made a mistake in the description of the problem. Thanks

Comment: Why not just add &filter=0 to the search query so that all results are shown?    This way the counts will match.  If you leave it with filters enabled but do not allow users to get to those results you are hiding results from them.

Comment: Good point, but we have very similar results(same pages but for different countries) and we don't want to show these pages.

Comment: There is no current workaround for the issue. I've encountered it as well and for now you have to stick with the way it behaves.

Comment: @Jeremy Garreau, thanks for reply!

Comment: In our case we created one GSA collection per country. This way, you can use X country's collection for X country's site (in query parameter to GSA), and only results for X country will show up.